# cloudformation: How to add an existing IAM managed policy to an Existing IAM ROLE

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I know the below scenarios

### Add a new IAM managed policy to an existing IAM role

```
Parameters:
  awsExampleRolesParameter:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Description: Names of existing Roles you want to add to the newly created Managed Policy

Resources:
  SampleManagedPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy'
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Sid: AllowAllUsersToListAccounts
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'iam:ListAccountAliases'
              - 'iam:ListUsers'
              - 'iam:GetAccountSummary'
            Resource: '*'
      Roles: !Ref awsExampleRolesParameter
```

### Add an existing IAM managed policy to a new IAM role

```
Parameters:
  awsExampleManagedPolicyParameterOne:
    Type: String
    Description: 'ARN of the first IAM Managed Policy to add to the role'
  awsExampleManagedPolicyParameterTwo:
    Type: String
    Description: 'ARN of the second IAM Managed Policy to add to the role'

Resources:
  RootRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Ref awsExampleManagedPolicyParameterOne
        - !Ref awsExampleManagedPolicyParameterTwo
```

Now i am looking for a scenario where

### how to attach a exisitng managed policies to existing role

```
Parameters:
  awsExampleRolesParameter:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Description: Names of existing Roles you want to add to the newly created Managed Policy
  awsExampleManagedPolicyParameterOne:
    Type: String
    Description: 'ARN of the first IAM Managed Policy to add to the role'
  awsExampleManagedPolicyParameterTwo:
    Type: String
    Description: 'ARN of the second IAM Managed Policy to add to the role'

......   WHAT TO DO HERE TO ATTACHE 
........ THE MANAGED POLICIES awsExampleManagedPolicyParameterOne and awsExampleManagedPolicyParameterTwo
........ TO THE ROLE awsExampleRolesParameter
```

Comment: Please provide your CloudFormatoin template and explain what's wrong with it. Any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that without a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). For that you have to develope a **lambda function** who will take ARNs of the the role and the policies as a input, and use AWS SDK (e.g. boto3) to modify the role.